# Usar JOIN y las operaciones de menor, mayor (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, join

Tengo un problema que no puedo resolver, me pidieron implementar "likes" tipo *facebook* en un blog, y lo programé y esta obteniendo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero ahora quieren que, dependiendo la valorización el artículo del blog sea más o menos confiable, en base de datos hice lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y, dependiendo la cantidad de *likes*, encasille al artículo en un nivel y de momento tengo esto:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_level;

SELECT SUM(`like`) AS result FROM wp_like WHERE id_post = 22;
```

Pero si aplico un *JOIN* solo me devuelve los valores que sean iguales y no se como colocar si es mayor qué y menor qué.

Desde ya, ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar como serían los rangos? Por que no esta claro si los valores son para indicar el `"desde"` o el `"hasta"`. Por ejemplo: ¿-8 likes donde iría? y ¿3 likes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pesar de que me gusta mucho más la propuesta de Patricio, te propongo esta alternativa, por si no tuvieras la posibilidad de modificar las tablas tal y como él te indica:

```
SELECT wp_like.*,IFNULL(content,'No confiable') content
  FROM (
    SELECT id_post,SUM(`like`) `like` FROM wp_like
      GROUP BY 1
  ) wp_like
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT l1.content,l1.likes,likes_max
      FROM wp_level l1
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT id,likes likes_max
          FROM wp_level
      ) l2 ON l1.id=l2.id-1  
  ) wp_level 
  ON `like`>=likes 
  AND `like`<IFNULL(likes_max,1e6);
```

Puedes sustituir el `GROUP BY 1` por `WHERE id_post=23` para que te categorice un único post.

Los valores `NULL` son los límites de los intervalos de los extremos.

Te paso el dataset en SQL para hacer las pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_like(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_user int,
  id_post int,
  `like` int,
  created_at datetime
  );
CREATE TABLE wp_level(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  likes int,
  content varchar(15)
  );
INSERT INTO wp_level (likes,content) VALUES
  (-5,'No confiable'),
  (0,'Poco confiable'),
  (5,'Exaltado'),
  (10,'Confiable');
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Answer (score 2):

Sería mucho mejor rediseñar `wp_level` para que cada fila inidicara un rango desde/hasta, para identificar univocamente el valor de confianza, pero también lo que puedes hacer con lo que ya tienes es filtrar los valores de likes mayores o iguales, ordenar por esta cantidad de forma descendente, y quedarnos con la primer fila:

```
SELECT TOP 1 L.content
       FROM wp_level L
       INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(`like`) AS result 
                          FROM wp_like 
                          WHERE id_post = 22
       ) R
       ON R.result >= L.likes
       ORDER BY L.likes DESC
```

En MySQL:

```
SELECT content
  FROM wp_level L
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(`like`) AS result 
      FROM wp_like 
      WHERE id_post = 24
  ) R
  ON R.result >= L.likes
  ORDER BY L.likes DESC 
  LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hola buenas noches recién leo sus comentarios, ayer me quede hasta tarde y resolví de esta manera (fea) igual ahora viendo sus respuesta voy a rehacerlo de una mejor manera.

```
SET @nConf = (SELECT wp_level.likes FROM wp_level WHERE wp_level.id = 1); # -5
SET @pConf = (SELECT wp_level.likes FROM wp_level WHERE wp_level.id = 2); # 0
SET @eConf = (SELECT wp_level.likes FROM wp_level WHERE wp_level.id = 3); # 5
SET @cConf = (SELECT wp_level.likes FROM wp_level WHERE wp_level.id = 4); # 10

SET @IDNConf = (SELECT wp_level.id FROM wp_level WHERE wp_level.id = 1);
SET @IDPConf = (SELECT wp_level.id FROM wp_level WHERE wp_level.id = 2);
SET @IDEConf = (SELECT wp_level.id FROM wp_level WHERE wp_level.id = 3);
SET @IDCConf = (SELECT wp_level.id FROM wp_level WHERE wp_level.id = 4);

SET @finish = (SELECT
    CASE
        # (-5) menor 0
        WHEN wp_post_level.likes < @pConf THEN @IDNConf
        # (3) mayor y igual 0 y (3) menor 5
        WHEN wp_post_level.likes >= @pConf AND wp_post_level.likes < @eConf THEN @IDPConf
        # (6) mayor y igual 5 y (6) menor 10
        WHEN wp_post_level.likes >= @eConf AND wp_post_level.likes < @cConf THEN @IDEConf
        # (11) mayor y igual 10
        WHEN wp_post_level.likes >= @cConf THEN @IDCConf
    END
FROM wp_post_level);
UPDATE wp_post_level SET wp_post_level.id_level = @finish WHERE wp_post_level.id = 9;
```

Sus respuestas me parecen más prolijas, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_post_level` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `id_post` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  );

CREATE TABLE `wp_level` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `likes` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  );

INSERT INTO `wp_level` (`id`, `likes`, `content`) VALUES
    (1, '-5', 'No confiable'),
    (2, '0', 'Poco confiable'),
    (3, '5', 'Exaltado'),
    (4, '10', 'Confiable');

CREATE TABLE `wp_like` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `id_user` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `id_post` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `like` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  );
```

Por último dejo la estructura que es igual a la que realizaste David excepto que agregue una tabla más (wp_post_level) para que se procesara el nivel y me acumulara la cantidad de likes con un SUM (wp_post_level.likes), cosa que no tenga que estar constantemente haciendo el recuento sino que toman el valor de este campo y en otro (wp_post_level.id_level) coloco el id de level que actúa como una clave forastera.

Comment: ¿Y cómo la mantienes actualizada? ¿Con un disparador?

Comment: Lo dejo como un procedimiento almacenado que se ejecuta a través de un disparador (cuando se de like), ¿es mala idea?

Comment: Es buena idea :) Es que hay que tener cuidado con los campos calculados precisamente porque se pueden quedar obsoletos, pero lo has resuelto perfectamente...